# Shaping one end of an object with many vertices

Tags: modifiers

I've got an ellipsoid (a circle stretched in 1 dimension) with *many* segments and rings.
I've cut off the left tip (on the Y-axis) and made it a (circular) face.
I'd like to stretch that face's dimensions along the X and Z axes so it's an ellipse.

(I'm trying to match the elliptical cross-sectional fuselage of an aircraft to seamlessly fit the circular nosecone.)

The key is, **I want the rest of the shape to follow suit, so it remains a smooth distortion along the length of the ellipsoid. i.e. the tail is not distorted at all.**

Basically, this is the Blender equivalent of a **PhotoShop perspective transform**, which allows you to turn  a rectangle into a trapezoid.

I'm self-helping, but Blender has so many types of possible deformations, I don't even know what I would look up in the manual. Not sure if it's a modifier, a deform, a warp or what.

[image]

Additionally, I'm going to be doing a lot of squashing and stretching of portions this ellipsoid - the belly is flat, the back is curved - i.e. the cross section will change shape gradually along the length of the fuselage. That's a more general thing I have to look into.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is what you need, but try looking up "proportional editing" (hotkey O - also can be toggled from the furthest right of the top-center icons above the 3D viewport..

Comment: Thank you. That is ALMOST perfect. The only problems are that 1] I can only select a sphere, and 2] I can only move, not scale. A sphere large enough to contain the *length* of the object is well enough to also contain the width - which means if I move a vert on the left of the fuselage to the right, it also moves the verts on the right of the fuselage to the right.

Comment: Under the proportional editing settings, try checking the "connected only" box. Also, you can always hide parts of the mesh that you don't want to be affected. Lastly, scaling works, you just have to select 2 (or more) points to "scale between".